# How to fix multiple SwiftUI previews

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I am working with SwiftUI and wrote the following example to present an issue I'm experiencing. When I add multiple Buttons, or multiple Texts, it creates two separate previews, but when I run the application on a device they load simultaneously. Attached here is a photo:

[image]

I cleaned my build folder, restarted my computer, and tried this on various other SwiftUI files but no success. Any ideas?

Comment: Your preview is different: `SwiftUIView_Previews`. It should be `ContectView_Previews`

Comment: @aheze Unfortunately that did not fix my issue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll need to put both `Text`s in a `VStack` or similar.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Example title")
            Text("Example title 2")
        }
    }
}
```

It seems that Xcode automatically adds a new preview for each separate view returned in the `body` var (It used to throw an error, but I think Xcode 12 changed some things).