# SwiftUI - too many previews

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, preview

How to show only 1 Preview for my views? Right now I have a problem with one view: **ItemView.swift**

After I run Live Preview of **ContentView.swift** and add few Core Data objects, my **ItemView.swift** shows Previews for all objects and test data. Having many objects, there are many previews and it slows down Xcode very much.

I have marked in code 2 places that are probably causing problems. I think it's either ForEach or ItemView_Previews struct. I have tried to fix it, but I cannot.

I am using Core Data. And have 1 Entity: Item, with 1 Attribute: date. But I think it's not a Core Data issue.

**ContentView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @State var paidFilter :Bool? = nil
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            List {
                
                ItemView(filter: paidFilter)
                
            }
            .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
            .navigationTitle(Text("Items"))
            .navigationBarItems(
                trailing:
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        let item = Item(context: self.managedObjectContext)
                        item.date = Date()
                        
                        do {
                            try self.managedObjectContext.save()
                        }catch{
                            print(error)
                        }
                        
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                            .font(.title)
                    }
            )
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
        
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        return ContentView()
            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
    }
}
```

**ItemView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ItemView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    var fetchRequest: FetchRequest<Item>
    var items: FetchedResults<Item> { fetchRequest.wrappedValue }
    
    init(filter: Bool?) {
        fetchRequest = FetchRequest<Item>(entity: Item.entity(), sortDescriptors: [])
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        // I think problem is here
        ForEach(items, id: \.self) {item in
            Text("\(item.date ?? Date())")
        }       
    }
}

struct ItemView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        //Or problem is here - Test data
        let testItem = Item.init(context: context)
        testItem.date = Date()
        return ItemView(filter: false)
            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
    }
}
```

Comment: First refactor your app delegate so you move the core data stuff into a separate class and then add the ability to run an in-memory version of sqlite instead of the ordinary one. Then you can have an in-memory version of your store with only a few items in it. This has been done and written about many times so do some research and I am sure you will find some good articles.

Comment: So do you mean that solution is to use some placeholders in Core Data, not actual objects?

Comment: No it will be exactly like an ordinary core data store with the same kind of managed objects but it will only exists in memory so any changes will disappear when the app quits.

Comment: I was thinking that the problem is with data flow in my views. Or maybe there is some way of providing test values in Preview strict, ignoring Core Data completely

Comment: You can of course do that but you need some layer in between then and not directly work against the NSManagedObjectContext

Comment: Actually I was hoping that there is another way of writing Previews struct so I could provide there dummy values and don’t use Core Data in preview at all. I just need to check how UI looks there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
var body: some View {
    // I think problem is here
    ForEach(items, id: \.self) {item in
        Text("\(item.date ?? Date())")
    }       
}
```

with

```
var body: some View {

    /// add VStack here!
    VStack {
        ForEach(items, id: \.self) {item in
            Text("\(item.date ?? Date())")
        }       
    }
}
```

Without a VStack or some other container, your body consists of multiple views. This makes Xcode generate a preview for each of them... see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65385721/14351818) for a similar question.

Comment: Thanks! Almost perfect. I am seeing just 1 preview with your fix. But I don't know why the number of items is doubled. Having 5 objects added in ContentView.swift, preview for ItemView.swift shows me 10 items. Do you know what could be the problem here?

Comment: @mallow try `Command` + `F` and search for "ItemView". You might have an extra one somewhere

Comment: Thanks @aheze, I have checked. It is not repeated anywhere. I have posted new question regarding this problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66913812/swiftui-previews-unexpected-data
I think I should fix it first and then I will come back to you to answer answer to this question. Because I am not sure if there is something wrong with my code or maybe is there a better way to handle Previews?
Thank you very much for trying to help me.

Comment: Thanks @aheze. Your solution works. After adding VStack I can see only 1 preview. The reason why I still had more items is because the code I have used for Preview is using Core Data objects created in Live Preview AND in-memory objects I have defined as testItems. I was not aware of this before. I was thinking that it uses in-memory test items ONLY.