# SwiftUI Previews - unexpected data

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, swiftui, preview

I would like to understand how to work with example data in SwiftUI Canvas Preview. I have done some searching, but didn't find answer to my problem.

**Question:**

Why Preview of my **ItemView.swift** view shows a mixture of example data I have provided + Core Data models created in Live Preview?

**Preview code example**

```
struct ItemView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        //Test data
        let testItem = Item.init(context: context)
        testItem.name = "Abc"
        return ItemView(filter: false)
            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
    }
}
```

**Expected behaviour:**
I was expecting to see UI preview with test data. So in other words, I was expecting to see "Abc" in Preview.

**Actual behaviour**
But what I am seeing is a list of mixed items: "Abc" repeated few times. "Test" repeated few times (as it's item.name attribute of Core Data objects being created with plus button in Live Preview).

Why is that? Why am I seeing Core Data objects, when I have specifically provided test values (testItem.name = "Abc")?

--

**FULL WORKING EXAMPLE**

**ContentView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @State var paidFilter :Bool? = nil
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            List {
                
                ItemView(filter: paidFilter)
                
            }
            .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
            .navigationTitle(Text("Items"))
            .navigationBarItems(
                trailing:
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        let item = Item(context: self.managedObjectContext)
                        item.name = "Test"
                        
                        do {
                            try self.managedObjectContext.save()
                        }catch{
                            print(error)
                        }
                        
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                            .font(.title)
                    }
            )
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
        
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        return ContentView()
            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
    }
}
```

**ItemView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ItemView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    var fetchRequest: FetchRequest<Item>
    var items: FetchedResults<Item> { fetchRequest.wrappedValue }
    
    init(filter: Bool?) {
        fetchRequest = FetchRequest<Item>(entity: Item.entity(), sortDescriptors: [])
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(items, id: \.self) {item in
                Text("\(item.name ?? "test123")")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ItemView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        //Test data
        let testItem = Item.init(context: context)
        testItem.name = "Abc"
        return ItemView(filter: false)
            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
    }
}
```

Comment: When you do `let testItem = Item.init(context: context)`, you aren't passing it into the `ItemView`. Basically you are initializing it and then throwing it away.

Comment: Hmm... But I can see this testItem in Preview. I am just surprised I can see it mixed with other objects. Should I rewrite my ItemView_Previews struct somehow to see ONLY the provided test values?

Comment: Try replacing `testItem.name = "Abc"` with `testItem.name = "ASDASDASDASD"`. Then see if that shows up.

Comment: Yes, that shows up. Now I can see a mixture of "ASDASDASDASD" (from my sample data) and "Test" (from Core Data objects created in Live Preview).

Comment: Ah ok. Ignore my first comment. Can you post code for `Item`'s init?

Comment: Do you mean this?
`let testItem = Item.init(context: context)
testItem.name = "ASDASDASDASD"
return ItemView(filter: false)
.environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)`

There is full code of my ContentView.swift and ItemView.swift under FULL WORKING EXAMPLE heading. Please tell me if you need anything more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why Preview of my ItemView.swift view shows a mixture of example data I have provided + Core Data models created in Live Preview?

1. the below line initiates context to your persistent data, so makes available all stored core data object to be fetched

   ```
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
   ```
2. the below line creates a new object in the context created above, so it is in context (though to stored) and available for fetching alongside of others stored.

   ```
    let testItem = Item.init(context: context)
   ```

Thus fetching object from this context ...

```
    return ItemView(filter: false)
        .environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
```

... makes all - stored and created - available in Preview.

Comment: Oh, so this is normal behaviour that I see testItem AND other objects in Preview? Is it possible to NOT fetch previously created objects from context and use ONLY testItem?

Comment: See my comments to your previous related post - you need to use different, in-memory, stack.

Comment: Or my comments in the question before that ;)